# Storing In an array php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `debonere_questions`", $this->db);

while($user_data[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($question)){
        $sub_question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `debonere_sub_question` WHERE`q_id`='".$user_data['q_id']."'", $this->db);

        while($user_data1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sub_question_result)){
            echo $user_data1['sub_question'];
        }
    }
```

I want store this in a single array.

Comment: when you say "this" what do you actually mean ?

Comment: which value you want to store?? and plz use mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: Use JOINs on your request

Answer (score 0):

Do something like that

```
$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `debonere_questions`", $this->db);
while($user_data[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($question)){
$sub_question = mysql_query(
   "SELECT * FROM `debonere_sub_question` WHERE `q_id`='".$user_data['q_id']."'",
      $this->db);
    while($user_data1=mysql_fetch_assoc($sub_question_result)){
        $array[] = $user_data1['sub_question'];
        }
}
```

And you should use MySQLi or PDO.